# Exception while copying the array using a foreach loop

Tags: c#

Can someone tell me why I'm seeing below exception when I use a foreach loop?

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException:
>   Index was outside the bounds of the array.

but I don't see this exception if I use for loop.
One thing I have noticed is index is starting at `1` if I use foreach loop.

```
int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] array2 = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };

int[] mergedarray = new int[array1.Length+array2.Length];
array1.CopyTo(mergedarray, 0);
array2.CopyTo(mergedarray, array1.Length);
Console.WriteLine(mergedarray.Length);

//for (int i = 0; i < mergedarray.Length; i++)
//{
//    Console.WriteLine(mergedarray[i]); ;
//}

foreach (var item in mergedarray)
{
    Console.Write(mergedarray[item] + " ");
}
```

Comment: In a `foreach` loop there is no notion of an index. `item` represents the current item taken from your array. I.e. it starts at `1` since the first item in `array1` is `1`. If you would set the first item to be `34` then it would start with `34` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with following line

```
 foreach (var item in mergedarray)
 {
    Console.Write(mergedarray[item] + " ");
 }
```

This needs to be

```
 foreach (var item in mergedarray)
 {
     Console.Write(item + " ");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` doesn't give you a index, instead it gives you the item directly out of the array, what you did only worked for you because the arrays were of the `int` type. You only need a index if you use `for`. In-depth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in

And your "index" started with 1 because your array started with that number.

The correct solution would be:

```
 foreach (var item in mergedarray)
 {
     Console.Write(item + " ");
 }
```

Pro tip:
You can easily join array items into a `string` using `string.Join` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join).
It takes first a seperator `string` or `char`, in your case the space `' '` or `" "`, and afterwards you array.

```
var joinedArray = string.Join(' ', mergedarray);
```

With regards, 2gjava.